# How to set datadir to different values based on the hostname in my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, configuration, my.cnf, mac-os-x

How to set `datadir` to different values based on the hostname in `my.cnf`?  I want to use the same `my.cnf` file on a Linux machine and a Mac OS X machine where the `datadir` should have different values.

Comment: One possibility is to modify the DB startup script on each machine to pass the --datadir=/your/data/path to mysqld. That way no modification is needed to your my.cnf file. A second option would be to use the "!include /etc/mylocal.cnf" directive in your global my.cnf & then have /etc/mylocal.cnf contain the specific datadir= directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution for that would be to keep the `my.cnf` file identical, and use symlinks on your machine sto point to whatever directory you want the data to be in. For example, assuming you `my.cnf` contains this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/mysql_data
```

On you linux host, you would:

```
cd /
ln -s /var/lib/mysql mysql_data
```

Add permissions to this folder for mysql user:

```
chown mysql:mysql /mysql_data
```